# Can someone explain this weird laptop drive setup with an mSATA SSD and conventional HDD?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I've got a Lenovo IdeaPad Y580 laptop in my office that I'm trying to figure out.

This is the partition setup I'm seeing:

[image: Windows Disk Management]

Upon loading the Disk Management console, it tries to initialize the mSATA drive and fails with the error, "cannot find the sector requested."

This is what GParted shows for the SSD:

[image]

This is what GParted shows for the HDD:

[image]

With *only* the HDD installed, the laptop will fail to boot (can't find boot sector)

With *only* the mSATA installed, the system will boot to Windows recovery mode.

So... what the heck is this?  I've never seen a setup like this before.  Is it possible to migrate the Windows installation to SSD so just the user files can be on the HDD?

Comment: If it was on a Mac I'd say it was a Fusion Drive; I don't know how to interpret it on Windows, but see if you can find something that can tell if it's a Logical Volume Group [LVG]

Comment: It looks like the mSATA SSD is the boot drive and also contains some information used to accelerate the HDD, particularly during the boot process.

Answer (score 0):

google expresscache and how it works. Maybe thats it?
asus uses that name "expresscache" for their software which is licensed from a different company, could be that lenovo also has it licensed from that company to use.

my asus laptop has 1tb 5400rpm HDD connected via SATA and a small 24GB SSD drive connected via mSATA.

the idea for mine is the windows installation, recovery, MBR, etc is all on the HDD, but expresscache software enables the SSD to be used as a cache drive. This is an old laptop, so its probably cuz SSD's were much more expensive at the time. The result is much faster access to things that get cached onto the SSD. Cold boot time i dont think is affected much, but things like waking up from sleep are MUCH faster (2 second wakeup from sleep) along with loading stuff the expresscache software caches onto the SSD.

My SSD is only 24gb so makes sense to just use it all as a cache SSD.

Since your SSD is bigger, and after i updated the expresscache software myself manually in the past, i know you can split a bigger SSD up if you choose to do so. Ex, if 100GB SSD, make a small partition (ex, 30gb) to be used for SSD cache purposes, then make a larger partition (ex, 70gb) to be used for OS installation, etc.